# How to install wkhtmltopdf on Shared Hosting?

Tags: linux, centos7, wkhtmltopdf, shared-hosting

I tried many ways to install wkhtmltopdf, but it wont work. I'm currently using hostinger for shared hosting and I have SSH access. The server is running on CentOS 7, please help.